# Horizontal space in itemize with different label

Tags: spacing, lists, itemize

```
\begin{itemize}
\item[Key point 1] 
\item[Key point 2]  
\end{itemize}
```

I want to change the bullets in "itemize" to other labels. The above works but the problem is that "Key point 1" and "Key point 2" now stretch beyond the left border of the page, so I need to add horizontal space to bring it back to the normal position. I cannot just add \hspace before \item. How can I do it?

Comment: A tabular would be a better option for such case... Dont you think so?

Comment: If it's possible with itemize, I'd like to use itemize.

Comment: Ok... but then \item[Key 1] and \item[Key 10] will need separate space to added? Or you want them aligned right? (with tabular any of this would be really easy)

Comment: Fortunately I won't have up to 10, so this is not a worry

Comment: Are you looking for the `description` environment?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A simple solution with the parameters of `enumitem`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\begin{document}

text\vspace{10pt}
\begin{itemize}[wide =0pt, labelwidth=\widthof{Key point 10}]
\item[Key point 1] Optional item here
\item[Key point 10] Another item
\end{itemize}

text

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Your code is exactly the same as koleygr's, is that a copy-paste mistake?

Comment: @TorbjørnT.: Oops! A problem with my clipboard manager. Indeed I copied koleygr's  code  to avoid having to type a full code, and replaced his specific code by mine. It's fixed. Thanks for pointing the problem!

Comment: +1 after the real code :P... I Didn't used `calc` package and tried to align too,but the options you used are really helpful for me. I will leave my answer just as an alternative with boxes.

Comment: @koleygr: Thanks! Your answer is fine too. I think we proceed differently: personally I favour using existing packages, patching them if necessary, as the authors are much more experienced than I am in low-level programming.

Answer (score 4):

Here is a solution:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\newlength{\mylength}
\newsavebox{\mybox}

\def\FindLength#1{%
\savebox{\mybox}{\hbox{#1}}%
\setlength{\mylength}{\wd\mybox}%
}%

\newenvironment{myitemize}[1]{%
\FindLength{#1}%
\begin{itemize}[leftmargin=19pt]
\setlength{\itemindent}{\mylength}%
}{%
\end{itemize}%
}

\begin{document}
text\vspace{10pt}

\begin{myitemize}{Key point 10}
\item[Key point 1] Optional item here
\item[Key point 10]   Another item
\end{myitemize}


text


\end{document}
```

I am sure there are better solutions, but it works with different lengths too, like "key point 2" and "key point 102"...

I don't know to explain the "leftmargin =19pt" but may be someone will help or I will find it later... (I found it through tests, and may be need to be changed according to your document class).

If you want any explanation just ask.

Here is the output:

[image]

and with same lengths:

[image]

Comment: why have you got `\hbox` here `\savebox{\mybox}{\hbox{#1}}%` ?  but you do not need `\savebox` at all, you can replace `\FindLength` by `\settowidth\itemindent{#1}`.   `\settowidth` is defined in the format it doesn't need a package

Comment: Thanks @DavidCarlisle... I will take a look. I knew `\settowidth` but was using this with `\usebox{\mybox}` because usually I measure heights... And so I am just used to it. I didn't knew `itemindent` and I will take a look very soon. Thanks again

Comment: there is a settoheight as well:-)

Comment: yes... and `\settototalheight` but with calc. The point there is that you need a box to measure the height. (At least I do) And thus I am used to the same way for widths too (And didn't knew the `itemindent` as an alternative)

Comment: no settoheight and settodepth are defined in the format as well as settowidth. I'm not sure what you mean by not knowing `\itemindent` I just took that example from your answer. and with `\setbox` you shouldn't use `\hbox` was the point of my initial comment

Comment: lol... I thought itemingent was not the length we (set) but the next work thar removes extra spaces or something if you give just a text. I see now. Thanks.