# How to make next node same width as previous?

Tags: tikz-pgf, nodes, width

Node TXT1 is automatically sized as well as node TXT2 which is following TXT1. But how to get TXT1 width so that it can be used with `text width` of TXT2?

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\tikzset
    {%
        BASICSTYLE/.style=
            {%
                align=left,
                draw=red
            }
    }
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \path node[BASICSTYLE](TXT1)
            {this is line 1\\this is line 2};
        \path node[BASICSTYLE,below=5mm of TXT1](TXT2)
            {this is ... long line one\\this is ... long line two};
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Do you mean the red rectangle around the first to be the same width like the second's at width? Or you want to change contents of lines too (break later)?

Comment: Ok... So, is this ok to give an initial text and then to adjust every rectangle to this initial texts width?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can calculate the width of `TXT1` using the `let` syntax. That is the total width though, so you need to subtract the `inner sep` and line width to get a value that can be used for `text width`.

[image: Output of code]

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,calc}
\tikzset
    {%
        BASICSTYLE/.style=
            {%
                align=left,
                draw=red
            }
    }
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \node[BASICSTYLE](TXT1)
            {this is line 1\\this is line 2};
        \path
            let
            \p1=(TXT1.east),\p2=(TXT1.west),
            \n1={\x1-\x2-2*\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgf/inner xsep}-\pgflinewidth}
            in
            node
            [BASICSTYLE,below=5mm of TXT1,text width=\n1]
            (TXT2)
            {this is ... long line one\\this is ... long line two};
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: +1 for the idea... I also think that the custom "hardcoded calculations" would be simplified with inner sep or something simmilar [not tested]

Comment: @koleygr What do you mean?

Comment: `\x1-\x2-2*\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgf/inner xsep}-\pgflinewidth`... you can change `inner sep` then too without worrying for the calculation

Comment: @koleygr Ah, that's right, I forgot that it works with `inner xsep`. (It doesn't work with `\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgf/inner sep}`.) Thanks, I'll edit.

Comment: No problem... trying to find a way to accept inner BASICSTYLE and to work... I am close but it seems dificult

Answer (score 3):

Here is a way:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\tikzset
    {%
        myrect/.style=
            {%
                draw,red,text=black,thick,minimum width=\mymaximumwidth
            }
    }

\def\mytext#1{\noindent\begin{tabular}{l}#1\end{tabular}}
\def\mytextafter#1{\noindent\setlength\tabcolsep{0pt}\begin{tabular}{p{\mymaximumwidth}}#1\end{tabular}}
\newlength{\mymaximumwidth}
\newsavebox{\mybox}
\begin{document}

\def\mywidernode{\mytext{Here is the text\\ with width that\\will be used in nodes}}
\savebox\mybox{\mywidernode}
\setlength\mymaximumwidth{\wd\mybox}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
       \path node (rect1) [draw,red,thick,minimum height=2cm] {\usebox{\mybox}};
       \node[myrect,below=1cm of rect1] (rect2) {\mytextafter{Here is another\\ text\\ with same width}};
       \node[myrect,right=1cm of rect2] (rect3) {\mytextafter{Here is another with bigger text and automatic linebreaks}};
       \node[myrect,above=1cm of rect3]{\mytextafter{test\\text\\here\\with last row breaking manually}};
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
\section{}

\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]

**1st Edit: (before @DavidCarlisle will see it and get disapointed that I didn't learn my lesson from his comments here: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/396972/120578):**

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{array}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\tikzset
    {%
        myrect/.style=
            {%
                draw,red,text=black,thick,minimum width=\mymaximumwidth,inner sep=5pt
            }
    }

\def\mytext#1{\begin{tabular}{@{\raggedleft}l}#1\end{tabular}}
\def\mytextafter#1{\setlength\tabcolsep{0pt}\begin{tabular}{p{\mymaximumwidth}}#1\end{tabular}}
\newlength{\mymaximumwidth}
\begin{document}

\def\mywidernode{\mytext{Here is the text\\ with width that\\will be used in nodes}}
\settowidth\mymaximumwidth{\mywidernode}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
       \path node (rect1) [draw,red,thick,minimum height=2cm,inner sep=5pt] {\mywidernode};
       \node[myrect,below=1cm of rect1] (rect2) {\mytextafter{Here is another\\ text\\ with same width}};
       \node[myrect,right=1cm of rect2] (rect3) {\mytextafter{Here is another with bigger text and automatic linebreaks}};
       \node[myrect,above=1cm of rect3]{\mytextafter{test\\text\\here\\with last row breaking manually}};
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
\section{}

\end{document}
```

Also fixed the spaces in start of text.

**Second Edit (automating for user):**

The user just has to give the text inside `\Startingtext` command and
begin the nodes by the command `\StartNode`. `\curstart` is the name of
our every current starting node.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz,pgf}
\usepackage{array}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\newlength{\mymaximumwidth}
\newsavebox{\mybox}
\newcounter{startnode}
\makeatletter
\def\mytext#1{\@ifundefined{pgf@sh@pi@\curstart}{\savebox\mybox{\begin{tabular}{@{\raggedleft}l}#1\end{tabular}}\usebox{\mybox}\setlength\mymaximumwidth{\wd\mybox}}
{\setlength\tabcolsep{0pt}\begin{tabular}{p{\mymaximumwidth}}#1\end{tabular}}%
}
\def\StartNode{\draw[myrect] node[draw] (\curstart)  {\usebox{\mybox}};}

\def\Startingtext#1{\stepcounter{startnode}\xdef\curstart{mystart\thestartnode}\savebox\mybox{\begin{tabular}{@{\raggedleft}l}\mytext{#1}\end{tabular}}
\setlength\mymaximumwidth{\wd\mybox}}
\makeatother

\tikzset
    {%
        myrect/.style=
            {%
                draw,red,text=black,thick,minimum width=\mymaximumwidth,inner sep=5pt
            }
    }

% The user just has to give the text inside `\Startingtext` command and
% begin the nodes by the command `\StartNode`. `\curstart` is the name of
% our every current starting node.
\begin{document}

\Startingtext{Here is the text\\ with width that\\will be used in nodes}


    \begin{tikzpicture}
       \StartNode
       \node[myrect,below=1cm of \curstart] (rect2) {\mytext{Here is another\\ text\\ with same width}};
       \node[myrect,right=1cm of rect2] (rect3) {\mytext{Here is another with bigger text and automatic linebreaks}};
       \node[myrect,above=1cm of rect3]{\mytext{test\\text\\here\\with last row breaking automatically}};
    \end{tikzpicture}\vspace*{40pt}


    \Startingtext{Small \\ width \\text}
       \begin{tikzpicture}
       \StartNode
       \node[myrect,below=1cm of \curstart] (rect2) {\mytext{Here is another\\ text\\ with same width}};
       \node[myrect,right=1cm of rect2] (rect3) {\mytext{Here is another with bigger text and automatic linebreaks}};
       \node[myrect,above=1cm of rect3]{\mytext{test\\text\\here\\with last row breaking manually}};
    \end{tikzpicture}\vspace*{40pt}


\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]